# CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE set but hardcoded vga-boot-parameter ignored?

Tags: linux, boot, bootloader, linux-kernel

I have build a custom linux kernel with the options:

```
...
CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE=y
CONFIG_CMDLINE="initrd=linux_os.gz root=/dev/ram0 init=/sbin/init ramdisk_size=25600 consoleblank=0 loglevel=2 console=ttyS1 vga=785"
...
```

I use syslinux as bootloader. With works correctly with the following configuration (same parameters as the hardcoded ones):

```
default MyConfig
prompt 0
label MyConfig
kernel vmlinuz
append initrd=linux_os.gz root=/dev/ram0 init=/sbin/init ramdisk_size=25600 consoleblank=0 loglevel=5 console=ttyS1 vga=785
```

But if I replace the last line with:

```
append initrd=linux_os.gz root=/dev/ram0 init=/sbin/init ramdisk_size=25600
```

it "fails" to boot (the vga-mode didn't change as expected). With [CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE=y](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE_OVERRIDE.html) the parameters configured in the bootloader should be ignored or am I wrong in this?

I'm using a vanilla 3.10.10-Kernel with no relevant patches (just replacing the boot logo) on x86. Its an pice of embedded hardware and I can not configure the boot-parameters, just replacing `vmlinuz` and `linux_os.gz` except for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digged trough kernel soure and found my answer: The video mode is set very early on x86 - even before switching to protected mode (`set_video()` in `main()` (arch/x86/boot/main.c). Evaluation of `CONFIG_CMDLINE_OVERRIDE` is done later in `setup_arch()` (arch/x86/kernel/setup.c). I have no real fix but at least a workaround:

in ./arch/x86/boot/video.c, replace

```
for (;;) {
    if (mode == ASK_VGA)
        mode = mode_menu();

    if (!set_mode(mode))
        break;

    printf("Undefined video mode number: %x\n", mode);
    mode = ASK_VGA;
}
boot_params.hdr.vid_mode = mode;
```

with

```
boot_params.hdr.vid_mode = 785;
set_mode(785);
```

(or any other video mode you want). This might break mode changing but I doesn't want to change modes ;)